# How to transpile arrow function while creating a babel plugin

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I m currently studying babeljs and the way they are transpiling code from ESX to ES5.

Actually, I m trying to write a really (really) simple plugin that would transpile some simple statements, and I'm stuck while trying to transpile arrow function and return statements.

Here's the code I want to transpile :

```
const x = () => null;
```

Here's what I would like to have :

```
var creatingAVariablex = function () {
    return null;
};
```

From now, I m having the following code inside my plugin :

```
module.exports = function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path, state) {
        path.node.name = "creatingAVariable" + path.node.name;
      },
      ArrowFunctionExpression(path) {
        /**
         * Here, I should transpile () => to function() {}
         * special case: when path.node.expression, I have to add curly around the body + return statement
         * I tried with the following stuff, but it seems that I'm missing something concerning the way
         * I should create the functionExpression
         */
        path.replaceWith(t.functionExpression(path.node.body));
      },
      VariableDeclaration(path) {
        path.node.kind = "var";
      }
    }
  };
};
```

I don't know where to start, and I can't find the API definition to create a `functionExpression`.

Does anybody know who I can handle this case ?

EDIT : I managed to make it work with

```
module.exports = function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path, state) {
        path.node.name = "creatingAVariable" + path.node.name;
      },
      ArrowFunctionExpression(path) {
        /**
         * Here, I should transpile () => to function() {}
         * special case: when path.node.expression, I have to add curly around the body + return statement
         * I tried with the following stuff, but it seems that I'm missing something concerning the way
         * I should create the functionExpression
         */
        path.replaceWith(
          t.functionExpression(
            t.Identifier("func"),
            [],
            t.BlockStatement([t.returnStatement(path.node.body)])
          )
        );
      },
      VariableDeclaration(path) {
        path.node.kind = "var";
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md?

Comment: I come from here but can't find a way to modify te arrowFunctionExpression to a functionExpression